# how to compute this complexity?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int max (int A[], int c, int d);

int main (void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int A[3] = {-95,52,3};
    int B[3][3];
    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(j < i)
            {
                B[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                B[i][j] = max(A,i,j); 
            }
        }
    }



}

int max(int A[],int c,int d)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int max = -100;

    for (i=c; i <= d; i++)
    {
        if(max < A[i])
        { 
            max = A[i];
        }
    }
    return max; 
}
```

I don't understand how to compute complexities. I think this is in n^2 but I don't know why it would be.

This program takes a single array and creates a double array based on the max from i to j. The output is correct.

Comment: I think it's O(n^3) because there's also the loop in `max`.

Comment: basicly you have `O(n²)` time the complexity of the `max()`, so it is in total `O(n³)`

Comment: ok that make sense. Is there anyway i can optimize this to make it run O(n^2)?

Comment: @user2101171 Perhaps, but please post that as a separate question. Also, if one of the answers below was helpful, consider marking it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by `n` you mean both the size of the `A` array as well as the two dimensions of `B`, you basically have *three* nested for-loops, one of them "outsourced" into the `max` function.

In the worst case (when `c` is `0` and `d` is `n-1`), each of them runs through `n` elements.

Thus your complexity is `O(n^3)`.

Comment: Actually, the argument I made is not sufficient to imply O(n^3). Imagine three nested for-loops: `for i from 0 to n: for j from 0 to n: if (i==j) for k from 0 to n: do_something_O(1); done; else: do_something_O(1); endif; done; done`. For this setup, you could make the same argument I made above, but the complexity is `O(n^2) + O(n) = O(n^2)`. A more thorough analysis is required, e.g., like the one I gave below.

Comment: Please stop upvoting, the answer is not really correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have the two outer for-loops (`i` and `j`) that run over `n` elements each. If `j<i` you simply do a `O(1)` operation, but if `i<=j` then you all `max`. This function has another for-loop which runs over `j-i+1` elements. Since we know that `i` and `j` are both bound by `n` this will be at most `n` elements.

We can analyze the nested for-loops simply by sums over the index variables:

[image]

So, the algorithm in total has a worst-case complexity of `O(n^3)`.

Comment: This should be added as part of your original answer, not as a separate answer.  Nice art work, but you only get one up-vote from me, and that's on the other answer (because it was right and submitted first).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I decided to put this as a separate answer because on second thought I didn't find my first one satisfactory. I would actually like to delete the first one now but can't since it has been accepted. Thanks for the upvote, though, one is plenty.